# How to avoid error "aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE"

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

This sql code throws an

> aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE

```
SELECT o.ID ,  count(p.CAT)
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Products p ON o.P_ID = p.P_ID 
WHERE count(p.CAT) > 3
GROUP BY o.ID;
```

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Replace `WHERE` clause with `HAVING`, like this:

```
SELECT o.ID ,  count(p.CAT)
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Products p ON o.P_ID = p.P_ID 
GROUP BY o.ID
HAVING count(p.CAT) > 3;
```

`HAVING` is similar to `WHERE`, that is both are used to filter the resulting records but `HAVING` is used to filter on aggregated data (when `GROUP BY` is used).

Answer (score 17):

Use `HAVING` clause instead of `WHERE`

Try this:

```
SELECT o.ID, COUNT(p.CAT) cnt
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN Products p ON o.P_ID = p.P_ID 
GROUP BY o.ID HAVING cnt > 3
```

Answer (score 3):

try this.
WHERE (select (count(p.CAT) > 3) from TableName)

Comment: Awesome, this did work wonders for me. I was in a situation where I could only change what was inside an already existing WHERE (thus not able to use having).

Answer (score 0):

Will self join will go for a toss with join where we have a condition to list prices that are greater than the median of the prices listed in the order table?

Eg. order_item, Order_Price

Since aggregate functions cannot be used in a WHERE clause >

```
select a.order_item_product_price, count(distinct 
a.order_item_product_price) from 
default.order_items a , default.order_items b
where a.order_item_product_price = b.order_item_product_price
group by a.order_item_product_price
having a.order_item_product_price > appx_median(b.order_item_product_price)
order by a.order_item_product_price limit 10
```