# Aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause in postgreSQL error

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, aggregate-functions

I was trying to execute this following query, and I am a beginner in writing `SQL` Queries, was wondering how can I achieve the following aggregate functions functionality doing in `WHERE` clause. Any help on this would be a great learning curve for me.

```
 select a.name,a.add,a.mobile from user a
     INNER JOIN user_info aac
        ON aac.userid= a.userid  
     INNER JOIN info ac 
        ON aac.infoid= ac.infoid  
    WHERE a.total < 8* AVG(ac.total) 
 GROUP BY a.name, a.add, a.mobile;
```

And this is the error I am getting in PostgreSQL:

```
ERROR:  aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause
LINE 1: ...infoid = ac.infoid where a.total < 8* AVG(ac.tot...
                                                             ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause
SQL state: 42803
Character: 190
```

Am I suppose to use `Having` clause to have the results? any correction on this would be a great help!

Comment: You want the `having` clause: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-agg.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails 3, getting a PGError: ERROR: aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause on a AR query of an object and its has\_many objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684486/rails-3-getting-a-pgerror-error-aggregates-not-allowed-in-where-clause-on-a-a)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid error "aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991729/how-to-avoid-error-aggregate-functions-are-not-allowed-in-where)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a window function in a subquery:

```
select name, add, mobile
from (select a.name, a.add, a.mobile, total,
             avg(ac.total) over (partition by a.name, a.add, a.mobile) as avgtotal, a.total
      from user a INNER JOIN
           user_info aac
           ON aac.userid= a.userid INNER JOIN
           info ac 
           ON aac.infoid= ac.infoid
     ) t
WHERE total < 8 * avgtotal
GROUP BY name, add, mobile;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon Linoff, I did exactly and it gave me the following syntax error: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near ";"
LINE 10: GROUP BY a.hash, a.package, a.version_name;
                                                   ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near ";"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 446` I have pasted exact query :( Do I need to add anything else?

Comment: @akiiddweeber . . . The closing paren on the subquery is now where it should be.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, what does "t" stands for is it like assigning a whole function with some name? and I ran the same now getting different error: 
`ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "a"
LINE 10: WHERE a.total < 8 * avgtotal
               ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "a"
SQL state: 42P01
Character: 386`

Comment: @akiiddweeber . . . The `t` is called a table alias.  It names a subquery or table for use in other parts of the query.  The code you are referring to has changed.