# How to fix error “aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE”

Tags: postgresql

How to fi this error

Err] ERROR:  aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE

this my query

```
select count(case daftar.daftar when 'sd' then 1 else null end) as sd,
 count(case daftar.daftar when 'smp' then 1 else null end) as smp,
 count(case daftar.daftar when 'sma' then 1 else null end) as sma
from daftar
join gelombang on  daftar.gel=gelombang.id
join ajaran on ajaran.id=gelombang.id_ajar
join tahun on tahun.id=ajaran.tahun
where daftar.status='terima' and daftar.pindahan='no' and tahun.id= max(tahun.id)
```

Comment: This problem already discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466123/error-aggregates-not-allowed-in-where-clause-in-postgresql

Comment: BTW: You can simplify the `CASE`expressions, e.g. `COUNT(daftar.daftar = 'sd' OR NULL)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: Aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause in postgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21466123/error-aggregates-not-allowed-in-where-clause-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use a subquery to calculate that max value:

```
select count(case daftar.daftar when 'sd' then 1 else null end) as sd,
       count(case daftar.daftar when 'smp' then 1 else null end) as smp,
       count(case daftar.daftar when 'sma' then 1 else null end) as sma
from daftar
inner join gelombang
    on daftar.gel = gelombang.id
inner join ajaran
    on ajaran.id = gelombang.id_ajar
inner join tahun
    on tahun.id = ajaran.tahun
where daftar.status = 'terima' and
      daftar.pindahan = 'no'   and
      tahun.id = (select max(id) from tahun)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use "HAVING" to tackle this:

> HAVING tahun.id= max(tahun.id)

```
select count(case daftar.daftar when 'sd' then 1 else null end) as sd,
 count(case daftar.daftar when 'smp' then 1 else null end) as smp,
 count(case daftar.daftar when 'sma' then 1 else null end) as sma
from daftar
join gelombang on  daftar.gel=gelombang.id
join ajaran on ajaran.id=gelombang.id_ajar
join tahun on tahun.id=ajaran.tahun
where daftar.status='terima' and daftar.pindahan='no' 
HAVING tahun.id= max(tahun.id)
```

Answer (score 3):

Aggregates functions we use only in SELECT block. You can use inner select for this case:`where daftar.status='terima' and daftar.pindahan='no' and tahun.id=(select max(id) from tahun)`

Comment: This is not completely correct. You may use aggregates in `HAVING` clauses, too.

Comment: thank for your kindness and advice I'm trying to learn aggregates

Answer (score 1):

use a subquery, group by or having clause