# aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using this query to find the unique records by latest date using postgresql. The error I am having is "aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE". [How to fix error “aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41277189/how-to-fix-error-aggregate-functions-are-not-allowed-in-where) Following this link I have tried to use inner select function. But this did not work. Please help me to edit the query. I am using PgAdmin III as client.

```
SELECT Distinct t1.pa_serial_
    ,t1.homeownerm_name
    ,t1.districtvdc
    ,t1.date as firstrancheinspection_date
    ,t1.status
    ,t1.name_of_data_collector
    ,t1.fulcrum_id
    ,first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire.date_reporting
From first_tranche_inspection_v2 t1
LEFT JOIN first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire ON (t1.fulcrum_id = first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire.fulcrum_parent_id)
where first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire.date_reporting = (
        select Max(first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire.date_reporting)
        from first_tranche_inspection_v2
        where first_tranche_inspection_v2.pa_serial_ = t1.pa_serial_
        );
```

Comment: In your subquery you select from `first_tranche_inspection_v2` but the MAX function relates to a field in `first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire`. Is this a typo? Or what do you want to achieve there?

Comment: Yes this is my requirement so I have joined these two tables

Comment: No, I mean MAX is meant to aggregate the table in question, so consequently the field you use MAX on would have to be a field of that table. As it isn't, you are not aggregating the table in the subquery, but simply refer to a maximum that you would have to determine outside of it. But outside of the subquery there is no aggregation. In short: you are doing something very wrong here. The question is: what is it you want to do?

Comment: what I am trying to do is -The info like pa_serial_, homeownerm_name, status..etc are obtained from first_tranche_inspection_v2 but other few columns are obtained from first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire and I want to obtain the latest records based on date_reporting from first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire table as this table contains same information on different dates and I need to obtain unique latest records

Comment: _Show_ us by way of sample data.

Comment: You are using the wrong table name in your subquery. (You probably got confused by the very long names, or your keyboard wore out)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to join the latest reporting questionaire per inspection. In PostgreSQL you can use `DISTINCT ON` for this:

```
select fti.*, rq.* 
from first_tranche_inspection_v2 fti
left join
(
  select distinct on (fulcrum_parent_id) *
  from first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire
  order by fulcrum_parent_id, date_reporting desc
) rq on rq.fulcrum_parent_id = fti.fulcrum_id;
```

Or use standard SQL's `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
select fti.*, rq.* 
from first_tranche_inspection_v2 fti
left join
(
  select 
    ftirq.*, 
    row_number() over (partition by fulcrum_parent_id order by date_reporting desc) as rn
  from first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire ftirq
) rq on rq.fulcrum_parent_id = fti.fulcrum_id and rq.rn = 1;
```

What you were trying to do should look like this:

```
select fti.*, rq.* 
from first_tranche_inspection_v2 fti
left join first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire rq
  on rq.fulcrum_parent_id = fti.fulcrum_id
  and (rq.fulcrum_parent_id, rq.date_reporting) in
  (
    select fulcrum_parent_id, max(date_reporting)
    from first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire
    group by fulcrum_parent_id
  );
```

This works, too, and only has the disadvantage that you read the table `first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire` twice.

Comment: I am using the first one...this works as a charm ..thanks

Comment: What if I need the count of records where rq.fulcrum_parent_id = fti.fulcrum_id in the same query for single record?

Comment: I think the third query you have written here would be useful to do this. What I also need now is the count of records for a unique record in fulcrum_id of first_tranche_inspection_v2 which matches fulcrum_parent_id of first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire? Please help

Comment: select fti.*, rq.* ,count
from first_tranche_inspection_v2 fti
left join first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire rq
  on rq.fulcrum_parent_id = fti.fulcrum_id
  and (rq.fulcrum_parent_id, rq.date_reporting) in
  (
    select count(fulcrum_parent_id) as count, fulcrum_parent_id,max(date_reporting)
    from first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire
    group by fulcrum_parent_id
  );

Comment: I am trying the above code but it says subquery has too many columns.

Answer (score 1):

`DISTINCT` often ends up being implemented with a `GROUP BY` query in many RDBMS.  What I think is happening in your current query is that there is already an implicit aggregation involving the columns in your `SELECT`.  Hence, the correlated subquery involving `MAX()` actually is an aggregation because of the `DISTINCT`.

One quick workaround might be to perform the original query without `DISTINCT`, then subquery the result set to retain only distinct records:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.pa_serial_,
           t1.homeownerm_name,
           t1.districtvdc,
           t1.date as firstrancheinspection_date,
           t1.status,
           t1.name_of_data_collector,
           t1.fulcrum_id,
           t2.date_reporting
    FROM first_tranche_inspection_v2 t1
    LEFT JOIN first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire t2
        ON t1.fulcrum_id = t2.fulcrum_parent_id
    WHERE t2.date_reporting = (SELECT MAX(t.date_reporting)
                               FROM first_tranche_inspection_v2 t
                               WHERE t.pa_serial_ = t1.pa_serial_)
);

SELECT DISTINCT t.pa_serial_,
                t.homeownerm_name,
                t.districtvdc,
                t.firstrancheinspection_date,
                t.status,
                t.name_of_data_collector,
                t.fulcrum_id,
                t.date_reporting
FROM cte t
```

Note that I went ahead and added an alias to the second table in your join, which leaves the query much easier to read.

Comment: I am getting this error "ERROR:  column t.date_reporting does not exist
LINE 13:     WHERE t2.date_reporting = (SELECT MAX(t.date_reporting)". Actually, date_reporting is coming from the secondary table "first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire" and irst_tranche_inspection_v2 is my primary table.

Comment: That makes no sense.  At this point, you should update your question with sample data and desired output to be clear.

Comment: "ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire"
LINE 3:         Max(first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire)"

Comment: Again, what you are trying to do makes no sense.

Comment: what I am trying to do is The info like pa_serial_, homeownerm_name, status..etc are obtained from first_tranche_inspection_v2 and other few columns are obtained from first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire and I want to obtain the latest records based on date_reporting from first_tranche_inspection_v2_reporting_questionnaire table