# PostgreSQL query to check minimum and maximum data

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have the example database here,

table products

```
id |  name  |  code  |  minimum_stock  |  stock  |  maximum_stock  
1     AAA      AAA            50           75           100
2     BBB      BBB            70           50           300
3     CCC      CCC            100          200          150
4     DDD      DDD            40           25           100
5     EEE      EEE            70           10           100
```

in this case i want to show only data who is stock exceed compared by their minimum_stock or maximum_stock(below or above their minimum maximum stock) and also i want to show datain safe stock position (between minimum and maximum stock),
stock value in here is a result from aggregate sum function

if i want only show data exceed minimum stock, the result output must be like this

```
id |  name  |  code  |  **minimum_stock**  |  **stock**  |  maximum_stock  
2     BBB      BBB            **70**           **50**           300
4     DDD      DDD            **40**           **25**           100
5     EEE      EEE            **70**           **10**           100
```

and if i want only show data exceed maximum stock, the result output must be like this

```
id |  name  |  code  |  minimum_stock  |  **stock**  |  **maximum_stock**  
3     CCC      CCC            100          **200**          **150**
```

and the last one the stock between minimum and maximum stock, it must be like this

```
id |  name  |  code  |  **minimum_stock**  |  **stock**  |  **maximum_stock**  
1     AAA      AAA            **50**           **75**           **100**
```

how can I do that?

Comment: do you want three queries or one?  are the `**` part of the requred output or just for emphasis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

Minimum Stock

```
Select * from table where stock < minimum_stock
```

maximum stock

```
Select * from table where stock > maximum_stock
```

between minimum and maximum stock

```
Select * from table where stock < maximum_stock and stock > minimum_stock
```

Comment: how about the stock is a result from sum operation, i tried it but its error

Comment: i got this message
ERROR:  aggregates not allowed in WHERE clause

Comment: @azy use HAVING instead of WHERE if there are agregates in the condition

Comment: check out this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20991729/how-to-avoid-error-aggregate-functions-are-not-allowed-in-where